# How to disable Bootstrap fix nav in the moble version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When some one visit mobile version / scaling the web page, Bootstrap navbar will remove fix position on the top. I want set normal scrolling view of navbar.

Bootstrap class "navbar-fixed-top"

[image]

[enter link description here](https://www.webadd.dev/pin/761144)

Answer (score 1):

try this one out.

```
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .navbar-fixed-top {
            position: absolute;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `navbar-fixed-top` and add the following styling to your media query:

```
nav.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I want to remove only mobline view position, not in the desktop version. "navbar-fixed-top " class I can not remove

Comment: which bootstrap version are you currently using??

Comment: You can still add the code without removing the class. If it still doesn't work, you could even try changing `nav.navbar` to `nav.navbar.navbar-fixed-top`